# Is "just some small business" a common idiom for the following dialogue?

Tags: idioms

> Speaker A: “You have something important to do?” I asked, hoping I
>   wasn't prying too much.
>
> Speaker B: “Just some small business.”

If not what's a more common reply for Speaker B?

Comment: This largely depends on the context. What must the B speaker imply? He might even say: "Not much really." or "Yes, I do".

Comment: As @SovereignSun mentioned, the reply can really vary depending on the context. However, if you want to use a *business* idiom specifically, I would change it to something like "Just a *little* business". Small business almost exclusively refers to small-sized businesses and is not used in this idiomatic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idiom is: **to take care of business or to do business**.

It would be more idiomatic for B to say: Just a **little business** to take care of.

Here: /some small business/ is not right. some small business means a business that is small, like a shop, or a person running a small business (a home-office business for example or a business that employs few people).